# Cannot connect to a SQL Server 2008 named instance hosted in a azure virtual machine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure, named-instance

When I try to connect to a named instance in a SQL Server hosted in a Azure VM, I get this message:

> *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)*

The problem is the SQL Server browser is not working properly, when I start the browser service it closes after a few seconds and the event log says

> *There are no instances of SQL Server or SQL Server Analysis Services.*

But I do have a named instance, I can connect locally to this instance.

I've re-installed SQL Server browser and the instance but ii does not work.

The host is an Azure virtual machine Windows Server 2008 datacenter.

Please help.

Thank you

UPDATE 11/08/2012
In fact I can connect to the default instance remotely, but I cannot do it with the named instance, by example, I connect remotely with the dns: , but if I try with \UAT, I cannot connect.

UPDATE
Well, it seems the problem is when someone tries to connect to a named instance the port 1434 for the SQL Browser must be open, so that means we need to create that endpoint in the azure management portal, the problem is the sql browser looks for the named instance and answer with a dynamic port. At the end I thought it was a lot of trouble to configure all that and anyways my sql browser was not detecting my named instance so I decided to create a new endpoint to listen for the named instance and assign an static port to that instance, now I can connect with the IP/Port. I'm still curious how can I configure the Azure VM, SQL Browser, SQL Sever and firewall to be able to connect with the dns/instance using the SQL Browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open up the 1433 endpoint through the firewall..did you follow these directions?
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/install-sql-server/

Did you try connecting with the DNS address?

Edit: 
Can you try a double slash(use "\\" instead of "\"):
"domain.server.net\\UAT"

Comment: In fact I can connect to the default instance remotely, but I cannot do it with the named instance, by example, I connect remotely with the dns: <domain.server.net>, but if I try with <domain.server.net>\UAT, I cannot connect.